# smoke comes out in bursts from moving object

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I am making a firework with a fuse to look like a S, and when i bake the flame, it is OK at first while the firework is not moving very fast, but when the firework speeds up, the flame comes out in bursts but I want it to come out continuously.

It looks fine at the beginning while not going too fast,
[image: beginning not very fast looks fine]

But when it catches speed the flame comes out in bursts
[image: when it catches speed the flame comes out in bursts]

My domain settings

[image: domain settings top]
[image: domain settings bottom]

My emitter settings

[image: emitter settings]

Blend file-
[blend file for download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14xC-U0qqEndgvN8ZR3veNhtrtdJgNpJf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your flow object's sampling subframes.
Select the object, go in the physics Properties tab and change the Sampling Subframes value.
[image: Sampling Subframes]
It can be animated but you need to know this : more subframes = more processing time

Comment: Thanks, i re-baked it and it worked perfectly